How can I count the number of consecutive days grouping by year and climate division?
I want to count the number of heatwaves, or consecutive days, for each climate division (CLIMDIV) and year from my dataframe. This dataset is filtered from a complete list of climate divisions and years with temperatures, so that I only have dates that are above 32C. Basically, I'm trying to see how many times in each year in each climate division that there were 2 consecutive days, 3 consecutive days, and 4 consecutive days over 32C, or heatwaves of various lengths.
I've tried using rle, but I can't figure out how to group the consecutive counts by climate division and year, nor how to create a list of different consecutive day counts. I also tried this code, which outputs the format I want, but the result was too small and not accurate when I counted from my list manually.
library(dplyr) 

df18 <- data.frame(
  CLIMDIV = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102,
              102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102),
  Year = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1970, 1970, 1970,
           1972, 1972, 1972, 1972),
  Date = as.Date(c("1970-01-01", "1970-01-02", "1970-01-03", "1970-01-06", "1970-01-07", "1970-01-09",
                   "1971-01-01", "1971-01-03", "1971-01-04", "1971-01-05", "1971-01-06",
                   "1970-01-01", "1970-01-02", "1970-01-03",
                   "1972-01-01", "1972-01-02", "1972-01-03", "1972-01-04")),
  Max_Heat_Index = c(32.2, 32.3, 32.4, 32.5, 32.6, 32.7, 32.8, 32.9, 33.0, 33.1, 33.2, 33.3,
                     33.4, 33.5, 33.6, 33.7, 33.8, 33.9)
)

# 2 day heatwaves
grouped_data2day <- df18 %>% 
  group_by(CLIMDIV, Year) %>%
  mutate(Consecutive = cumsum(c(1, diff(Date) != 1))) %>%
  group_by(CLIMDIV, Year, Consecutive) %>%
  summarize(Count = n()) %>%
  filter(Count >= 2) %>%
  summarise(days2over32C = n()) 

# 3 day heatwaves
grouped_data3day <- df18 %>% 
  group_by(CLIMDIV, Year) %>%
  mutate(Consecutive = cumsum(c(1, diff(Date) != 1))) %>%
  group_by(CLIMDIV, Year, Consecutive) %>%
  summarize(Count = n()) %>%
  filter(Count >= 3) %>%
  summarise(days3over32C = n()) 


Here is one option which first completes the data set to get full sequences of dates, then uses consecutive_id to add an id for each heat wave. Afterwards I compute the length or number of days of each wave and finally the counts by number of days using count:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df18 %>%
  group_by(CLIMDIV, Year) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Date = full_seq(Date, 1)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(
    id = consecutive_id(!is.na(Max_Heat_Index)),
    .by = c(CLIMDIV, Year)
  ) |>
  filter(!is.na(Max_Heat_Index)) |>
  count(CLIMDIV, Year, id, name = "days_over_32C") |>
  count(CLIMDIV, Year, days_over_32C)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   CLIMDIV  Year days_over_32C     n
#>     <dbl> <dbl>         <int> <int>
#> 1     101  1970             1     1
#> 2     101  1970             2     1
#> 3     101  1970             3     1
#> 4     101  1971             1     1
#> 5     101  1971             4     1
#> 6     102  1970             3     1
#> 7     102  1972             4     1


Here is a similar option with dplyr:
library(dplyr)

df18 %>%
  arrange(CLIMDIV, Year, Date) %>%
  mutate(Consecutive = cumsum(c(1, diff(Date) > 1)), .by=CLIMDIV, Year) %>%
  summarise(consecutive_days = n(), .by = c(CLIMDIV, Year, Consecutive)) %>%
  count(CLIMDIV, Year, consecutive_days)

CLIMDIV Year consecutive_days n
1     101 1970                1 1
2     101 1970                2 1
3     101 1970                3 1
4     101 1971                1 1
5     101 1971                4 1
6     102 1970                3 1
7     102 1972                4 1

